# Picloud scp with rsa file not working

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, scp

I am using picloud which is a high performance cloud service run on top of amazon ec2. I am trying to copy files into a newly created "environment" in my account. I am however unable to use the scp command to copy files from my local machine into picloud env that I have created.

The usual way to SSH into the picloud env is as follows:

```
ssh -i picloud_rsa picloud@ec2-54-242-89-28.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

But when I try to replace ssh with scp using the following format:

scp -r ~/path_to_the_directory  -i picloud_rsa picloud@ec2-54-242-89-28.compute-1.amazonaws.com

I get the following error:

```
cp: -i: No such file or directory
cp: picloud@ec2-54-242-89-28.compute-1.amazonaws.com/picloud_rsa: Permission
```

And If I try the following:

scp -r ~/Desktop/AllFolders/GMU/Fall\ 2013/yelp_phoenix_academic_dataset_duplicated/  picloud_rsa picloud@ec2-54-242-89-28.compute-1.amazonaws.com

I get just the permission denied error:

```
 cp: picloud@ec2-54-242-89-28.compute-1.amazonaws.com/picloud_rsa: Permission denied
```

I have absolutely no idea how to use scp in this case and would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `man scp`, you will see it requires parameter `-i identity_file` is ahead of the actual URIs of your file resources.

Answer (score 1):

The query I used was:

```
 scp -i picloud_rsa -r ~/my_path_to_directory picloud@ec2-54-242-89-28.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/picloud
```

The solution was to pass the -i flag along with the rsa file in the beginning right after the scp call.

Comment: You'd do many future googlers a favor by accepting your own answer as the solution :)